# Can I use genetic distances in form of a .csv file to create a tree in R using ape ?

Tags: r, dna-sequence, phylogeny

It is my first time using R for phylogenetics work and I was wondering if I could do that. It seems a rather trivial job and I think there must be a very small code for this, but I am unable to get it done. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You really should give a sample of your input data to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps you can point to an example of the type of output you want ("tree" is a pretty generic term). Have you looked at the [documentation](http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/ape.pdf) or the [vignette](http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/vignettes/MoranI.pdf)?

Comment: Well its a symmetric square matrix where the cells indicate value of genetic distance (calculated using MEGA) and diagonal entries are all zero.

I want to import this csv file into R and plot a dendrogram basically.